# TableLayout Orientation Problem

Tags: android, tablelayout

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/test_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TableRow android:id="@+id/column_01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/column_01_header"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Column 01 Header" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:id="@+id/column_02" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/column_02_header"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Column 02 Header" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

The output is (vertical)

```
Column Header 01
Column Header 02
```

But I want output like (horizontal)

```
 Column Header 01 Column Header 02
```

Comment: Add second TextView(column_02_header) in same table row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the rationale for using TableLayout? You need to have both TextView in same TabelRow to get what you desire. Different rows would be aligned one below the other.

Comment: Accord to me attribute orientation="horizontal" at TableLayout level should put bot TableRows in horizontal fashion. Isn't it?

Comment: No that is not correct TableLayout does not have that attribute it borrows it from its parent LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting Column Header 01 in a row and Column Header 02 in another row.So obviously it is vertical.Put two in a row

Comment: Accord to me attribute orientation="horizontal" at TableLayout level should put bot TableRows in horizontal fashion. Isn't it?

Comment: Is there anything to do with height/weight attributes?

Comment: For your first comment,NO?Row means the row.If you put views in a row that will take different column.For the second you can modify height,weight but that is different and will not make two column that are two row